# Buffering Input files and parallel processing in java

Tags: java, multithreading, io, buffer

I have a collection of 1000 files in gz format. I want to process them in chunks in parallel, say 8 in each round. When I let every thread opens a file and read from disk that resulted in a significant delay due to many processes trying to read from different locations.

I just wonder if there is an efficient method to handle multiple files reads? Or shall I buffer all the files into memory first (e.g. all 8 files and then hand the buffers to the threads). If so, what would be the best way of buffering files? bufferArray? or some alternative structures?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a fixed size pool of say 8 (because you have 8 cores) you may find this is reasonably efficient as decompressing the files is cpu intensive.

You may find however that this is no faster than using 4 threads or only 2 because the real bottleneck is reading the data from disk.  If this is the case, the only thing you can do is get a faster disk. e.g. mirror the disk, or use an SSD which can be 20x faster.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're swamping your process with 1000 threads. Threads aren't particularly lightweight (e.g. each will grab by default 512k of stack space).

A more efficient model may be to use a thread pool (via [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)) and tune it for the optimal number of simultaneous threads on your system (e.g. you've suggested 8 above - I'd suggest this hinges to some degree on the number of free CPUs you have).

Each `.gz` file would be represented by one `Callable` submitted to the executor, and the executor will look after running multiple jobs simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks Brain. This is what I'm doing right now with a fixed pool size based on the number of free cpus and each file is represented with a Callable. This is not efficient.